# Test for length of ARG parameter in SecRule - Mod Security

Tags: mod-security

What is the most efficient way to limit the length of a http request parameter using Mod Security? For example, to limit WordPress comment length :

```
SecRule ARGS:comment "^.{65530}"
```

Would this regex expansion slow mod-security down significantly?

Or would this be the fastest?

```
SecRule ARGS:comment "@gt 65530" "t:none,t:length"
```

Comment: Surely it has to be faster using gt -> If nothing else than because the OWASP CRS team uses gt for a similar length check in at least one of their rules - and I'd expect them to be most knowledgable at performance tuning this sort of thing....